# Error on Request

Tags: .net

I am having an issue with the following code:

```
Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"].ToString();
```

The error that I got is:

> Error 72  An object reference is
>   required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'System.Web.UI.Page.Request.get'

I am just using .NET 4 on web apps. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the `Page.Request` object inside of a static method, which is what I'm guessing is happening.

Comment: Dahhh ... yes you are right. Didn't realise we put inside the static method. Thanks again.